# How to send data from python program to php to store data on online data base?

Tags: php, python

Is it possible to send data from python program using get and post method to php program ,php reads the data and insert it to mysql live web host?

Comment: This is way too broad. Provide your code. What have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about a php script that you will run from the command line?

Otherwise if you will host your php file on a webserver you can use the request library in python to send post data to your php scritp then process it normally in php (it will have $_POST populated)

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Otherwise json.stringify your data in python and pass it as an argument to the php script 
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php